# Swift Remainder function and Rounding

Tags: swift, double, rounding, division

I am making my own specific graphing framework and am having trouble with dealing with some simple remainder if statements.

I would like the X-Axis to be logarithmic. Every time the user pans the graph it changes the X-Min and X-Max values by the translation.x amount.

I have the following code

```
for i in Int(xMin)...Int(xMax) {
    let logValue = Double(log10(Float(i)))
    let rounded = logValue.rounded(toPlaces:3)

    if rounded.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 0.1) == 0 {
        //Draw division line
        print("Got Here")
    }
}

extension Double {
    /// Rounds the double to decimal places value
    func rounded(toPlaces places:Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```

If I put breakpoints in my code, I can see that if rounded has a value of 1.3, the code never reaches the print line.  If I manually enter the value of rounded to be 100, again, the print line is never reached.

I have had no problem so far using the % remainder operator for Integers, however cannot figure out where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the underlying computation is binary instead of decimal.

We can use [Decimal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal) (since Swift 3) to do better.  Here's a quick and dirty mod function for illustration:

```swift
// a mod b = a - b*floor(a/b)
func mod(_ a: Decimal,_ b: Decimal) -> Decimal {
    var d = a/(b)
    var f : Decimal = 0
    NSDecimalRound(&f, &d, 0, .down)
    return a-(b*(f))
}
```

With normal floating-point calculations:

```
var i = 1.3
var j = 0.1
i.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: j) // 0.09999999999999998

i = 1.3
j = 0.15
i.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: j) // 0.1000000000000001
```

With Decimal:

```
var a : Decimal = 1.3
var b : Decimal = 0.1
mod(a, b) // 0

a = 1.3
b = 0.15
mod(a, b) // 0.1
```

We still need to take care:

```swift
var a : Decimal = 0.906 // 0.9060000000000002048 conversion to decimal issue

// Specify the significant digits directly
a = Decimal(sign: FloatingPointSign.plus, exponent: -3, significand: Decimal(906)) // 0.906
mod(a, Decimal(0.1)) // 0.006
```

So careful rounding and/or allowing for some small "epsilon" error margin should still be done.  (Comparing to exact numbers like 0 is probably not a good idea).

Answer (score 0):

Always remember that floating points on computers are messy, because of all kinds of rounding errors on the way. Many programmers I know, including myself, have been prone to thinking that dividing by 10 (decimal) is a clean operation. The problem is just that a constant like fx 0.1 translates into a rounded number in binary floating point. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error#Real_world_example:_Patriot_Missile_Failure_due_to_magnification_of_roundoff_error for a more technical explanation.

In general, avoid comparisons with equality for floating point numbers, because rounding errors will always get in your way.

If you print out the result of your truncatingRemainder call like this:

```
let rounded = logValue.rounded(toPlaces:3)

let remain = rounded.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 0.1)

print("rounded \(rounded)   remain \(remain)")
```

you get fx

```
rounded 0.845   remain 0.04499999999999993
rounded 0.903   remain 0.002999999999999975
rounded 0.954   remain 0.05399999999999991
rounded 1.0   remain 0.09999999999999995
rounded 1.041   remain 0.04099999999999987
rounded 1.079   remain 0.0789999999999999
rounded 1.114   remain 0.01400000000000004
```

Notice that even the clean 1.0 constant has a messy result for truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 0.1).

Comment: Thank you for this, I have managed to get it working by using a 'is less than' criteria, however this still seems like a work around and an invitation for other 'unwanted' values to get through.